# What happens to weakSelf and strongSelf in a block when the same block is executed multiple times?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

#### PREFACE

According to the [Clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), "For __weak objects, the current pointee is retained and then released at the end of the current full-expression." Which to me indicates that if I do this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self doSomethingInBackgroundWithBlock:^{
    if (weakSelf) {
        [weakSelf doSomethingInBlock];
    }
}];
```

NOTE

If you reference @dasblinkenlight's answer below, you'll notice that there is a possibility of `weakSelf` becoming `nil` before `doSomethingBlock`.

Assuming `doSomethingInBlock`, does start with `weakSelf` existing, the rest of it should run no problem and there's no risk of `weakSelf` becoming `nil` before it has finished executing.  However, if I were to run this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self doSomethingInBackgroundWithBlock:^{
    if (weakSelf) {
        // Guaranteed to be retained for scope of expression
        [weakSelf doSomethingInBlock];
        // weakSelf could possibly be nil before reaching this point
        [weakSelf doSomethingElseInBlock];
    }
}];
```

The work around that is suggested is to take `weakSelf` and convert it to a strong variable inside of the block, like this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self doSomethingInBackgroundWithBlock:^{
    __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        [strongSelf doSomethingInBlock];
        [strongSelf doSomethingElseInBlock];
    }
}];
```

#### QUESTION

What happens to the `weakSelf` and `strongSelf` during multiple iterations of the same block? Is there a chance that in `processBlock()`(below), self could exist for some objects and not for others?

#### EXAMPLE

For example, if I were processing an array of objects in the background using something like this, where `processBlock` contains references to self:

```
- (void) processValuesInBackgroundWithArray:(NSArray *)array usingBlock:(void (^)(id))processBlock {
    for (id ob in array) {

        // Block is called for each Object

        // Is there a chance that self will exist for some objects and not for others?
        processBlock(ob);
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self processValuesInBackgroundWithArray:someArray usingBlock:^(id object) {
    __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        [self doSomethingWithObject:object];
        [self doSomethingElseWithObject:object];
    }      
}];
```

So the block references `strongSelf` from `weakSelf`, but the block is executed multiple times.  Is there a chance that `strongSelf` might become `nil` in between iterations of objects in an array?

Comment: The point of "restrongification" is to guarantee self is either nil or an actual value in the entire block, which is better than the alternative of letting the weak reference expire somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @CodaFi - yea, I get that part of it. Mostly just wondering about retaining from execution to execution.

Comment: Well, that should give you your answer.  The lifetime of self, not being tied to the block, is tied to whatever you do with the object.  It's possible for it to go dead in the block, but only because you lose all strong references to the parent object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that in your first example the `weakSelf` inside the `if` would be non-`nil`, because the block has two full expressions that reference it:

- the `if (weakSelf)` check is the first full expression
- the `weakSelf` in `[weakSelf doSomethingInBlock];` invocation is the second one.

Therefore, your trick with `strongSelf` should be applied even when there is only one `weakSelf` invocation "protected" by the `if` statement.

> Is there a chance that in processBlock()(below), self could exist for some objects and not for others?

Since there is no guaranteed `__strong` reference in a stack frame preceding the `processValuesInBackgroundWithArray:` call, `self` may become released between iterations of the loop, but only in a situation when the call of your last code snippet happens on a `__weak` or an unretained reference to the object containing the method from your last snippet.

Let's say that your last code snippet is inside a method called `testWeak`, in a class called `MyClass`:

```
-(void)testWeak {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self processValuesInBackgroundWithArray:someArray usingBlock:^(id object) {
        __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (strongSelf) {
            [self doSomethingWithObject:object];
            [self doSomethingElseWithObject:object];
        }      
    }];
}
```

When the call is made like this

```
[myClassObj testWeak];
```

and `myClassObj` is `__strong`, the `self` object inside `testWeak` would be retained outside the call by the strong reference to `myClassObj`, so your code would be good, with or without the `strongSelf` trick.

When `myClassObj` is weak, however, and the last `__strong` reference gets released concurrently with the running loop, some objects inside the loop would end up seeing a `nil` `weakSelf` inside the block. The only difference that the `strongSelf` is going to make is preventing that `doSomethingElseWithObject` would be called on `nil`, while `doSomethingWithObject` would be called on a non-`nil` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added a note about my first block in the question. I am a touch confused about the last part, is there any chance you could include a short example.  Otherwise, give me a minute to reread and absorb it so I understand it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Logan `self` may exist for one iteration of the block then be deallocated when that iteration of the block ends. E.g. the strong reference in the block may have been the final thing keeping it allocated. In that case, the weak reference will have been nilled before the next iteration begins.

Comment: Note that you don't need to check for weakSelf in an if in Objective C - it's safe to just call a method on weakSelf. If weakSelf is nil, nothing happens when you call a method on it. This is one of main principles of ObjC - checking for nil is almost never required. You work under the assumption that method calls simply won't execute if the object is nil. With strongSelf, it's a matter of style, but the convention is "if (!strongSelf) return;" rather than putting code inside the if block. Whichever you want to follow :)